# Extremely slow internet connection on Kubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kubuntu, intel

Running a speed test on my Kubuntu system gets me about 2.7MBPS download speed, but on my phone, I get around 60MBPS. My signal bar is only showing 1 bar whilst being within 5 meters of the router, yet My phone gets full bars. I've checked `/lib/firmware/`, as specified on my Wifi drivers website and the drivers are installed. My Wifi adapter is an Intel Wireless-AC 9462. Thank you.

Comment: Laptop or desktop computer? 1 bar suggests that your connection is not good. Distance is only one factor.

Comment: @Nmath I'm using a desktop computer. The signal seems to vary time to time. Sometimes getting 3 bars, sometimes getting 1. Whilst using my old Windows OS, I would be getting full bars and upwards of 60MBPS. Now it's at 2MBPS.

Comment: If your WiFi adapter is inside a desktop chassis, it's basically inside a faraday cage and also surrounded by a bunch of other unshielded electronic devices that weren't built with WiFi in mind. Laptops and mobile phones are designed differently. I suggest using an Ethernet cable for your desktop.

Comment: @Nmath My Wifi Antennas are both outside my chassis, I double-checked they were properly screwed in and nothing was touching them. But I also never had this speed problem with my Windows OS.

Comment: You can maybe try to use a live session to rule out of this is an issue with something in your installed system, but the fact that it works and the signal strength is poor pretty much indicates that it's a physical issue and not software.  Wifi performance can literally change with the weather among **so many other** factors so I'd suggest not getting hung up on assuming that Windows/Ubuntu has much to do with it.

Comment: OK, first question... are you connecting to a 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz wireless network? What channel? What channel(s) is your router set to use for each network? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `ifconfig`.